# WPF - Bind Grid Rows to List of Model

Tags: wpf, data-binding

So I have a list of persons, and would like each row in my grid to correspond to a element in the list.
The trick is - I would like each attribute of a person to have a different control.

For example I would like the name attribute to use a textbox, the age attribute to use a dropdown box, and the isfemale attribute to use a checkbox.

In other words I want a grid of repeating rows, where is row is a set if different controls.
EDIT:
How do I set each column in the datagrid to a different type of control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so are you looking for `DataGrid` then?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx

A table of rows + columns, where each column has different controls?

you can hide the column headers, and adjust the styling of the grid to make it *look* like a list, if you really want it to look like a list.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain the question well. Let me rephrase - How do I set each column in the datagrid to a different control?

Comment: by changing the values of the column templates. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columns.aspx